# pavucontrol level base vs 100%

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, pulse-audio, volume-mixer

trying to understand what is `pavucontrol` doing. On the screenshot you can see that there are volume sliders where one ca nchoose from `base` or another percent value.

[image]

What is the meaning of `base`. In the past I saw some cards didn't have an actual control over mic volume, just software boost/reduce. I'm almost sure at least one of the below cards is like that. In ALSA I just didn't see the option to change volume. But how do I recognize this situation in `pavucontrol`?
For example when I reduce volume below `base` level, I'm pretty sure this is only a software reduction. But how about 100%? And I even see option for more than 100%.

**Update:** seems like probably this card does support hardware volume control based on the `pacmd` reported `HW_VOLUME_CTRL` flag:

```
$ pacmd list-sources
...
index: 34
        name: <alsa_input.usb-0d8c_C-Media_USB_Headphone_Set-00.analog-mono>
        driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
        flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAM
IC_LATENCY
        state: SUSPENDED
        suspend cause: IDLE 
        priority: 9449
        volume: mono: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
                balance 0.00
        base volume: 26281 /  40% / -23.81 dB
        volume steps: 65537
        muted: no
...
```

Comment: If you do a `pacmd list-sources`, you can see that base is an attribute. It's always 100% for `monitor` sources (those that reflect sinks), and for my cards, it's 100% for the USB webcam without volume control, and 30% for the in-built line-in. By default, volumes are 100%. So I'd assume volume is pure software control, as with the sinks, with 100% for "no change of hardware level". I've no idea where the `base` value comes from, or what it means, possibly it's some informative value that's available in the codec.

Comment: @dirkt, interesting is that the default position is `base`. So initially I thought this is the unaltered hardware level. But it is too low so I went to 100%. I want to record at the hardware native level, then I can do normalization in `audacity`. But not sure yet whether `base` or `100%` is the native volume. I'm updating my question now. If you put the `pacmd` command as an answer I'd upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like 100% is the max volume supported by the hardware while “base” is some default volume determined by pulseaudio.

From https://gavv.github.io/articles/pulseaudio-under-the-hood/#volume-range

- “base”

  Determined dynamically for every device. Defines backend-specific default volume that may be not as loud as the “norm” volume. May be equal to the “norm” volume.

  Mapped to the volume where the analog output is at some kind of normalized, pre-defined voltage level. For S/PDIF cards set to the volume where the output PCM samples are unscaled.
- “norm”

  Constant. Maximum hardware volume of a card (100%, 0 dB). If a card includes a proper amplifier, this volume may be very loud.

  For cards with an amplifier, volumes below this point employ hardware amplification, and volumes above this point employ digital (software) amplification.

  For cards without an amplifier, digital amplification is always used, both for volumes below and above this point.

  For cards without the decibel volume flag, volumes above this point are internally truncated the “norm” volume.

Comment: Indeed, your answer makes lots of sense. it would be nice if this was better defined or configured in PA. For my outputs 100% is the norm and I can go beyond with the risk of clipping peaks. OTOH, for my mic and line-in inputs base is the norm (10%) and I get heavy clipping beyond 15%. Interestingly I can get way beyond 100% which makes no sense in most cases (I'm suspecting that level of sensitivity is allowed to plug in a turntable which requires much higher preamplification). It would be much easier to control if the base was at 100% on that scale unless configured for phono input.